# AndroidManifest having 2 launcher, but launch the same activity. Anything I miss?

Tags: android

I have in my AndroidManifest.xml two activities that I could launch

```
        <activity android:name=".ExperimentActivity"
            android:label="Experiment">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When I install, there's two icons, `Main` and `Experiment`. However, when I launch, both also launch the `ExperimentActivity`.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the exact package  like

```
android:taskAffinity="com.yourpackage.MainActivity"
```

and

```
android:taskAffinity="com.yourpackage.ExperimentActivity"
```

to your activity tag .

Hope this helps.....

Comment: I also get another way of doing so. That's adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to my Experiment. That also does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, normally you only launch the Main Activity, which is declared as your launcher in the manifest. All other activities then get launched from the Main Activity.
You should only declare one Launcher Activity in your manifest.
E.g.:

```
  <activity android:name=".ExperimentActivity"
            android:label="Experiment">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- declare your own filters if you need them -->
                <!-- for example parent activities -->

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing so, which is to add the following to my `ExperimentActivity` scope.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

i.e.

```
    <activity android:name=".ExperimentActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="Experiment">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```